# Vertical scrollbar for Highstock or can I wrap flags?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I’m working on a customized version of a timeline using Highstock. I’m using flags to hold data for each week on the timeline (see screenshot). However, I’m having an issue when there are more than 4 flags during a week. The vertical axis does not scroll so the extra flags (anything greater than 4 in a week) get cut off.

Is there a way to create a vertical scroll for these flags within the Highcharts container?

If not, I'd like to do the following:

- If there are greater than 4 flags in the same week, add a ‘more’ link
  above the 4th flag.
- On the ‘more’ click event, show the next 4 flags for that week in the next column (that week plus one day).
- Then set the zoom view to 2 weeks (so there is
  room for the extra flags to be displayed).
- X = weekEndingDate (<= 4 flags)
- XplusOne =  X (same weekEndingDate)
  plus one day

https://jsfiddle.net/SkiWether/xtefxoh5/

[image: Highstock timeline using flags]

```
$.each(flagData[0].weekEndingData, function(i, flag) {
    var testValueNumber = flag.testValue;
    var week = flag.weekEnding.split('/');
    var x = Date.UTC(week[2], parseInt(week[0]) - 1, week[1]);

    flagSeries.push({
        x: x,
        fillColor: '#6a7b87',
        states: {
            hover: {
                fillColor: '#6a7b87',
                cursor: 'none'
            }
        },
        title: '<div class="flagMiniContainer">Test Value ' + testValueNumber + '</div>'
    });

    // Return Product Block Image and Date
    $.each(flag.productBlocks, function(j, block) {
        flagSeries.push({
            x: x,
            title: '<div class="flagContainer"><div class="innerText"><span>' + block.productBlockName + '</div><span class="innerImage"><img src="' + block.imagePath + '" width="75" height="52"></span></div>'
        });

    });

});
```

Comment: You can vote for that feature [here](http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api/suggestions/2364547-add-navigation-bar-for-y-axis-in-highstock). Also try workaround posted there. I am not sure what kind of troubles you have with implementation your logic. I would use `chart.events.redraw` to loop over all flags and check if any timestamp has more than 4 labels and add HTML button "More" with click event action to show more points accordin to your description. Using `series.setData()` to translate flags after click will be helpful.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try them both.

Comment: @PawełFus I've tried using the vertical scrolling example that you posted above but it's not quite working. I'm hoping you could possibly take a look at my updated code: https://jsfiddle.net/SkiWether/xtefxoh5/6/ Thanks!

Comment: Hmm.. which example do you refer to?

Comment: Sorry. It was on the voting page for vertical scrolling:  http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/kbs3b/

Comment: Your HTML structure is a bit different, see: https://jsfiddle.net/xtefxoh5/7/ However, I am not sure if in your case it is useful - most of the time, bottom navigator will be hidden.

Comment: Thank you. Yeah, I could probably try to force a scrollTo bottom sorta thing to initially go to the navigator. Unfortunately I noticed if I added more boxes then the same issue happens with the content of the boxes not being shown.

Comment: Yes, it is. I think you should set height of the `#container`to be `(max_number_of_boxes * 100 + 200)` pixels. I mean, something like that (numbers may not be exact).

Comment: @PawełFus I wasn't able to get this working so I tried adding a 'more link', similar to my original screenshot. I got that partially working but I'm having issues with the rangeSelector buttons and the view not rendering correctly. Anyway, getting the vertical scroll to work is the ideal solution but I can't get that working using your reference above (max_number_of_boxes * 100 + 200). I'm pulling my hair out. :-) Can you possibly show me an example again? Thank you.

Comment: Hmm.. I mean something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/ohg32hc2/ (line #62 gets number of boxes and line #91 sets height of the chart).

Comment: Thank you. I'll see what I can do with it. @PawełFus